# Find the particular solution of the PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the PDE $$-\frac{\partial ^2 w}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial y^2}=1.$$

I've found that the general solution of this PDE is given by $$w(x,y)=\frac{1}{4}(y^2-x^2)+g(y-x)+f(y+x)$$ for some functions $f$ and $g$.

I'm now given the conditions \begin{align*} w(x,0)&=0, \\ \frac{\partial w}{\partial y}(x,0)&=0,\\w(0,y)&=0,\end{align*} so that the PDE is defined on the domain $A \cup B=\{y>0,y>x\} \cup \{x>0,x>y\}$.

How do I apply these conditions? The first two on their own give me $w(x,y)=y^2/2$, but this doesn't take into account the nature of the domain and doesn't allow me to use the third condition.

Comment: Obviously $w(x,y)=0$ is solution : Put it into the PDE and into the conditions to check it. The consequences are for you.

Comment: @JJacquelin I made an error in the definition of the PDE. The RHS should have been $1$, not $0$. I've changed this now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you got $u$ from as it's not in your equations at all! Let's assume you meant $w$
Applying the boundary conditions to your general solution, one at a time result in:
$$-x^2/4+g(-x)+f(x)=0$$
$$g'(-x)+f'(x)=0$$
$$y^2/4+g(y)+f(y)=0$$
you can change the dummy variable on the last equation and sum it with the first one:
$$g(-x)+g(x)+2f(x)=0$$
Derivative of this would be:
$$-g'(-x)+g'(x)+2f'(x)=0$$
replacing $f'(x)$ from the second boundary condition:
$$g'(-x)=g'(x)/3$$
replacing this into the second boundary condition:
$$g'(x)/3+f'(x)=0$$
You can now take derivatives of the first and third boundary conditions and use the above two equations to solve for $f(x)$ and $g(x)$

Comment: Sorry, I did mean $w$! I've made an edit.